# How to print variable which contains HTML

Tags: php

One field of my mysql table contains body of an email received, now when I fetch this value in variable of PHP and just try to echo it just shows actual code.
How could i make to display as HTML-:
HTML stored in mysql-:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://myntra.myntassets.com/assets/banners/2014/3/12/1394610923636-footwear_micro-banner_160_120_mini.jpg" width="700" height="154" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP-:

```
<?php 
///......get value from DB and assign it to variable $body.
$body="$content";
echo $body;
?>
```

Comment: You want the tags to be visible when you echo it right?

Comment: What do you mean "it shows actual code"? Can you give a short example? Could it be there there is a `<pre>` tag somewhere?

Comment: yes sir, I am new to PHP sometimes could not handle such issues. Need someone to help

Comment: `$body=$content;
echo $body;` no quotes around `$content` unless you actully want the string `$content` to display

Comment: @Dagon: Of course the double quotes are superfluous here, but that doesn’t change anything.

Comment: everything changes something

Answer (score 0):

When you insert the data into your database I bet you are using `html_entities` over it.

Which is quite a good thing actually.

To get your html back, try using `html_entity_decode()`  on the content you need to serve as html.

Beware of XSS attacks though.

Comment: _“Which is quite a good thing actually”_ – no, it is of course not.

Comment: depending on what you need to do, it can not be. but 99.99% of the time, it IS a good thing.

Comment: For just inputting data into the database, in 100% of cases it is _not_ a good thing.

Comment: I am using mysql_real_escape_string($header) ; but I don't know how to get it back.

Comment: This has nothing to do with “having a clean DB” (no matter what you actually mean by “clean” here).

Comment: @abhinavdixit using `stripslashes()` - @CBroe : clean as cleaning user inputs and by default disabling XSS stuff.

Comment: That should not be done at database level, but when the data is _output_ into the specific context “HTML”.

Comment: I can't agree with this. Everything server-side must be clean in my point of view. If you have data in your db you are not sure of, you have serious dev issues in my opinion, because third party clients might be using these datas the wrong way. Safety by default is not a bad thing.

Comment: Since you might want to use this data in a _different_ context than “HTML” at some point, it would be _nonsense_ to store it _treated_ for the context “HTML” already. And your definition of “clean” just doesn’t make any sense – there _is_ nothing “unclean” about storing _raw_ data in your database; it’s the other way around – storing it in any other form than it’s _raw_ form is “unclean”. // If your _third party clients_ make unjust assumptions, then that is _their fault_. _“Safety by default is not a bad thing.”_ – this is not safety by default, it is just _corruption_ of the data.

Comment: You are just mixing up the data _storage_ layer with a specific _presentation_ layer here – and there is no justification for that.

Comment: Plus, what's the point storing raw HTML to use it in another context than sending it to a browser?

Comment: If you can’t _train_ your trainees to do stuff right, that’s your problem. Don’t let them work on projects where security is a concern then. And that you can’t imagine any use case right now should already prove how _short-sighted_ your approach is.

Comment: I rely on security, and I'd rather encode something to decode it then if it can prove useful in some way. Here, it is obviously, because as this example shows it, it's better have trouble serving raw html than serving raw html everytime by default.

Comment: _“I rely on security”_ – and that’s exactly what you are doing __wrong__ – you _rely_ on your data already being handed to you as “secure”, instead of taking the _appropriate_ measures at the point where you are _processing_ that data in a specific context. But I think we can end this discussion now – you seem to be to stubborn to realize where you are going wrong; hopefully this realization will come over time once you gather more experience, and hopefully at least other people reading this are not gonna follow your erroneous ways.

Comment: Ok dude, except I'm not judging your neither your method, I said every method has it's plus and cons. I don't know who's stubborn here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to display the HTML content of your email.
[htmlentities](https://www.php.net/htmlentities) should work. Try this-

```
echo htmlentities($body);
```

Answer (score -1):

try to do this

```
$body="'".$content."'";
echo $body;
```

cause when you add single quotation to the html code it's executed before printed 
or you have to add \ before every "
for example

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
```

i tried the both ways and they worked fine

Comment: This just adds single quotes around the output, it does not change how the browser treats the output at all.

Comment: yes it's just like when you print some data and add <td> or any other tag you do it like echo $body.'</td>';